# Comparing datetime to current time using PHP

Tags: php, datetime

Given `$some_date` equal to `2015-02-12 10:28:04`, how can I determine whether it is not older than `X` hours of the current time using PHP (and not MySQL)?

Comment: either date_diff() or date_sub() function would help.

Comment: You can use DateTime::diff http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Comment: Seems like date_diff()/date_sub() are alias to the datetime class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will determine if your date is less than 2 hours from the current datetime

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime(); //set current datetime to variable
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/Detroit')); //set timezone if you like
$fdate = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); //change format to year - month - day, hour, minute, seconds

$some_date = strtotime('2015-02-13 18:30:04'); // this is your datetime.  use your time or change $some_date to your variable
$new_date = strtotime($fdate) - $some_date;
$minute_date = $new_date / 60; // convert to minutes
$hour_date = $minute_date / 60; // convert to hours

print $hour_date;

if($hour_date > 2){ // change the 2 to whatever you want it to be.
    print "more than two hours";
}else{
    print "less than two hours";
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Adam.  Not concerned about timezones/daylight savings time.  Just whether the even happened more than X hours before a current event.  The past time obviously is provided via a DB, and while this is easy using the DB, don't wish to do so.

Comment: Updated.  Is this what your looking to do?

Comment: I think so Adam.  Not sure what `$fdate` is, however.  If `current_date`-`2015-02-12 10:28:04` is less than say 2 hours, I wish to do something.

Comment: $fdate is the current datetime reformatted to year/month/day hour/minute/seconds format.  Y-m-d H:i:s.  I just called if `$fdate` for final date.  I am updateing the code.  I just tried it and it works

Comment: This should work for what you want.  you can fancy it up a bit cuz i just whipped it together.  i will further explain how it works if you want

Answer (score 2):

`strtotime` and the `DateTime` class are our friends.  Where `$x` is hours:

```
if(($time = strtotime($some_date)) > $time + ($x * 360)) {
    //do something its more than X hours
}
```

That likely won't work across daylight savings time boundaries, so maybe:

```
if(($time = strtotime($some_date)) > strtotime("+$x hours", $time)) {
    //do something its more than X hours
}
```

Comment: So, just bring everything to seconds, and deal with it as appropriate?

Comment: Thanks AbraCadaver.  Not concerned about daylight savings time (but good point).  Just concerned about server time.  Application is voiding some request (i.e. resetting a password) after X number of hours after it was initiated.

Comment: Better to not use calculations with date and time, you never know.